# Jstree stuck loading

Tags: php, ajax, json, jstree

I have to create a tree from a mysql database. The problem is that jstree stuck on loading. here is my code:
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#treeViewDiv").jstree({

```
                "json_data" : {

                    "ajax" : {
                        // the URL to fetch the data
                        "url" : "myfolder/getData",

                        "data" : function (n) {
                            // the result is fed to the AJAX request `data` option
                            return {
                                "operation" : "get_children",
                                "id" : n.attr ? n.attr("id").replace("node_","") : 1
                            };
                        }
                    }
                },
```

and thats how I get datas:

```
    public function listAll(){       
    $q = <<<QRY
    SELECT
    id, title,lft,rgt
    FROM $this->dbname.my_table_name
    ORDER BY lft ASC
    QRY;
```

and:

```
    $sourcesRepo = new myclassRepository($this->get('database_connection'), 'mydbname');

    $pages   = $sourcesRepo->listAll();


    $return=array(
        'pages' => $pages,
    );
    return $this->query($q);
```

Can anybody help, what the problem can be?

Comment: listAll() function seems to be incomplete. Where is the DB fetch part? Or is this all of code for listAll()?

Comment: What is the purpose of $return variable when you dont return it? Please post entire code for listAll() and its usage where you return ajax